# Laravel Create multiple records in Pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a function in our Laravel 5.8 app that would add multiple records to a pivot table. At present we have the following setup;

- Users
- Training Courses
- Users Training Courses (pivot table for the above relationships, with a few extra fields)

I want to be able to show all users in the database, then check their name, pick a training course and hit "Add" and it'll create a record in the pivot table for each user that was selected.

I can't figure out where to start with this - it seems like I need to have a "for each user selected, run the store function" loop in the controller, but I have no idea where to start.

I wasn't sure if there was an easy way to do this in eloquent or not. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships You can also pass an array so don't need to go through manual loops.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent does this automatically if you set up the relationships correctly and you don't have to worry about pivot tables.

```php
class Users
{
    public function trainingCourses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TrainingCourses::class);
    }
}

class TrainingCourses
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the [`save()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) to create the relationship.  But I find it better to wrap this function inside a helper method that you can use throughout your code:

```php
class Users
{
    ...
    public function assignTrainingCourse(TrainingCourse $trainingCourse)
    {
        return $this->trainingCourses()->save($trainingCourse);
    }
}
```

In your code, you could then do something as simple as this:

```php
$user = User::find(1);

$trainingCourse = TrainingCourse::find(1);

$user->assignTrainingCourse($trainingCourse);
```

Building on this, suppose you have the following route to assign a training course, where it expects a `trainingcourse_id` in the request:

```php
Route::post('/users/{user}/trainingcourses', 'UserTrainingCoursesController@store');
```

Thanks to route model binding, Laravel can inference the parent model (`user`) from the URL, and your controller might look like this:

```php
// UserTrainingCoursesController.php

public function store(User $user)
{
    $trainingCourse = TrainingCourse::find(request()->input('trainingcourse_id'));

    $user->assignTrainingCourse($trainingCourse);

    return back();
}
```

Of course, you'll want to put some validation in here, but this should get you started.